# Regex to match all the words that is not a interpolated string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all the words except interpolated string i.e, strings which are inside #{...}

'The variable 1 is #{**vf a sr**} abc'
'the variable 2 is #{**var**}'
'the variable is something'
'The variables are #{ **b** } and #{**&c&**}'

I want to avoid matching all the strings in **{..}** , as well as if there is any space character or special symbols inside it.

I have written one regex : `/(?<![#{\w])\w+(?![\w}])/gi`.
It has one negative lookbehind (?<![#{\w]) and one negative lookahead (?![\w}).
The problem is its still matching the **a** in {**vf a sr**}.
And the regex also breaks if there is a special character like **{&c&}**, in this case it now match the **c**.

https://regex101.com/r/lEieyw/5

Comment: What's the goal, just get the words, or replace them? For such cases you can use [this trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick): *match what you don't want but **capture** what you need*. See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V5JKQL/1), simple regex - isn't it. Now just [get the matches of group 1](https://tio.run/##LY7LCsIwEEX3@YorBU1QW9wJJe78A3c@IA1pG0kfJLEKNd9eY3UzDHPOvcxdDMJJq3u/HfbTJLvWeVhVqRc4smQ838J4XYc3vTzXLKtyQozycN5GvDrVCoOwWhRGYQftkIxDCQFnA0QhV1F/1jpCShs@t6bqpSSNecYWnKN9GMPISIAmLTt7FLKOqvCy3qCyPQM/4EsBXdJ44HyH5RKzgcU//zeA7/edUanpql8Jy2cS4gxxD2SaPg).